# Не прикрепляется клавиатура в aiogram 3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

В ТГ боте имеется главная клавиатура main_kb, которая открывается после команды `/start`. Далее пользователь выполняет некоторые действия, после чего ему выдается сервисная клавиатура `service_kb`.

```
await message.reply("some text", reply_markup=service_kb)
```

После обработки запроса выводится сообщение "ваш запрос обработан, результат ..." и к этому сообщению требуется вновь прикрепить пользователю главную клавиатуру, но через метод

```
await message.answer("ваш запрос обработан, результат ...", reply_markup=main_kb)
```

клавиатура не прикрепляется, когда через метод

```
await message.reply("ваш запрос обработан, результат ...", reply_markup=main_kb)
```

все работает как надо. В чем может быть проблема?

UPD: добавил код клавиатуры

```
keyboard = [
    [
        KeyboardButton(text="1"),
        KeyboardButton(text="2"),
        #KeyboardButton(text="3")
    ],
    [
        KeyboardButton(text="4"),
        KeyboardButton(text="5")
    ]
]
main_kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=keyboard,
    resize_keyboard=True,
    one_time_keyboard=True,
    selective=True
)
```

Comment: Подробностей добавь, что за клавиатура, есть ли ошибка, потому что если без этого, то у тебя всё работать должно

Comment: Добавил код клавиатуры. Ошибок нет, просто клавиатура на answer не прикрепляется

Comment: Добавь () в конце `reply_markup=main_kb()`

Comment: Так в ошибку сваливается